# wrong Intent receveid in Activity from Notification (in Service)

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service, android-pendingintent, android-notifications

I have a really strange problem. I've write a Service with 2 SimpleNotifications called by a Thread, but when i click on them to start the DestinationActiviy i discovered that the received Intent contains the extras of the last Notification clicked.

For example:
Step 1) SimpleNotification 2 is called
Step 2) SimpleNotification 1 is called
Step 3) Click on SimpleNotification 2

Result: DestinationActivity shows: "SimpleNotification1"

Could you tell me why? I'm really surprised  about that...

This is the code of my Service:

```
public class MyLocalService extends Service {

private final static String LOG_TAG = "MyLocalService";

private final static int MAX_NOTIFICATION_NUMBER = 10;

private final static int SIMPLE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

private NotificationManager notificationManager;        

private BackgroundThread backgroundThread;

private Notification notification;

private PendingIntent pIntent;
private int notificationNumber;
private PendingIntent pIntent2;
private Intent intent;
private Intent intent2;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        backgroundThread = new BackgroundThread();
        backgroundThread.start();
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Service Created");

}

public void sendNotification1(){
        notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,"Simple Notification1", System.currentTimeMillis());            
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        intent = new Intent(this, DestinationActiviy.class);
        intent.putExtra("notificationType", "Simple Notification1");
        pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);     
        notificationNumber++;
        notification.number=notificationNumber;
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Simple Notification1","Simple Notification Extended", pIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}

public void sendNotification2(){
        // Creiamo la Notification
        notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,"Simple Notification2", System.currentTimeMillis());            
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        intent2 = new Intent(this, DestinationActiviy.class);
        intent2.putExtra("notificationType", "Simple Notification2");
        pIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent2,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);     
        notificationNumber++;
        notification.number=notificationNumber;
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Simple Notification2","Simple Notification Extended", pIntent2);
        notificationManager.notify(2, notification);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Service Started");
        notificationNumber = 0;
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
        backgroundThread.running = false;
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Service Destroyed");
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
}


private final class BackgroundThread extends Thread {
        private final static long MIN_DELAY = 2000L;            
        private final static long MAX_RANDOM_DELAY = 10000L;
        public boolean running= true;
        public void run() {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "BackgroundThread Started");                     
                Random random = new Random();
                while(running && notificationNumber<MAX_NOTIFICATION_NUMBER){
                        long randomDelay = MIN_DELAY + Math.abs(random.nextInt() %MAX_RANDOM_DELAY);
                        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Delay is (ms) "+randomDelay);
                        try{
                                Thread.sleep(randomDelay);
                                }
                        catch(InterruptedException ie){

                        }
                        sendNotification2();
                        sendNotification1();
                }
                stopSelf();
        }
}
}
```

The Service start from a MainActivity:

```
public class LocalServiceTestActivity extends Activity {

private Intent serviceIntent;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    serviceIntent = new Intent(this,MyLocalService.class);
}

public void startLocalService(View button){
    startService(serviceIntent);
}

public void stopLocalService(View button){
    stopService(serviceIntent);
}    
}
```

And DestinationActivity:

```
public class DestinationActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.notification_activity);
    // Otteniamo le informazioni associate all'Intent
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputView);
        textView.setText(extras.getString("notificationType"));
    }
}

}
```

I've tryed also with same Intent, with same pendingIntent with same notification or viceversa with different Intent, pendingIntent (like this code)... I don't know how fix that. Please help me, Thanks.

Comment: There is not enough information here. Where is the service being started?

Comment: I've edited my question. Is it clear now? :-)

Answer (score 4):

When you create the PendingIntent for the second Notification here:

```
pIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, 
                intent2,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

you specify the `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` flag. Because the second Notification and the first Notification are "the same" (ie: they are Intents for the the same Activity), this flag prevents a new PendingIntent from being created. Instead, it just causes the existing PendingIntent to be modified with the Extras from the new one. See [documentation for PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT).

So what you've got are 2 Notifications that both share the **same** PendingIntent. No matter which one of the Notifications you select, you will always get the Extras from the second one.